# Solving a Diophantine equation in three variables as a parametric equation in one variable

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, parametric

Let’s say that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are integers such that
$$(b^2+2)^2=(a^2+2c^2)(bc-a).  \tag{$\star$}$$
By brute force search, I think I’ve discovered that
$$(a,b,c)=(5d+1,3d+1,d+2), \qquad d=\dots,-2,-1,0,1,2,\dots$$
Certainly that condition satisfies ($\star$), since plugging in to either side gives
$$81d^4+108d^3+90d^2+36d+9 = 81d^4+108d^3+90d^2+36d+9,$$
as desired.

> **QUESTION:** How do I *prove* those are the only solutions to ($\star$)?

__

> **EDIT**: Observe that the existing “solution” is equivalent to saying that
>   $$(a,b,c)=(5c-9,3c-5,c), \qquad c=\dots,-2,-1,0,1,2,\dots$$
>   are all solutions. That is to say, if $c$ is any integer satisfying ($\star$), then $(a,b)=(5c-9,3c-5)$ completes a solution of ($\star$). Does that consitute “necessary and sufficient conditions” on ($\star$), or do I need to show that there can be no other possible solutions?

Comment: To answer your last question, in order to give necessary and sufficient conditions for $(\star)$ you *must* also prove those are the only solutions.  I imagine it's quite common for an algebraic variety to admit parametrized solutions that don't cover all solutions.

Comment: Here's a simple example that shows that there are more solutions than just the parametrized family you've found so far: $(-9, 5, 0)$.

Comment: if you have a solution $(a,b,c)$, you  get a new solution with $(a,-b,-c).$ All the solutions found so far either fit your pattern or do so if the involution is applied